# How to transform client request body with a zuul filter?

Tags: java, spring, netflix-zuul

I want to use Zuul to authenticate, transform and forward request from a client to internal services. The goal is to hide from the client a legacy API.

What I have in mind is: a client sends a POST request with the JSON representation of an object A to the API Gateway where Zuul is embedded. The API Gateway transforms the body from A to LegacyA and send it to the internal service.

For example, I search a way to transform the following JSON:

```
["hello","world"]
```

in this JSON:

```
{hashCode("hello"):"hello", hashCode("world"):"world")}
```

I want to use a pre-filter. But I have problem to rewrite a valid request.

Do you have any idea how can I do that?

I have written this filter:

```
public class RestZuulFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    public RestZuulFilter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

        HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapper = new MyWrapper(ctx.getRequest());
        ctx.setRequest(wrapper);

        return null;
    }

    class MyWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        /**
         * Constructs a request object wrapping the given request.
         *
         * @param request The request to wrap
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the request is null
         */
        public MyWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
            super(request);
        }

        @Override
        public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            ServletInputStream inputStream = this.getRequest().getInputStream();

            List<String> test = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, new TypeReference<List<String>>() {
            });
            Map<Integer, String> result = test.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(String::hashCode, str -> str));

            byte[] json = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(result);
            ServletInputStream response = new ServletInputStreamWrapper(json);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that I have is with the Content-Length which is not updated accordinally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the following example of a request body being transformed. I suppose this should work for you.

```
    InputStream in = (InputStream) context.get("requestEntity");
    if (in == null) {
        in = context.getRequest().getInputStream();
    }
    String body = StreamUtils.copyToString(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    body = body.toUpperCase();
    context.set("requestEntity", new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

For the complete class:

https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sample-zuul-filters/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/samplezuulfilters/UppercaseRequestEntityFilter.java

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to use the HttpServletRequestWrapperclass inside your filter

```
import com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter;
import com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext;
import com.netflix.zuul.http.ServletInputStreamWrapper;
import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import static com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext.getCurrentContext;

public class ModifyBodyFilter extends ZuulFilter {

@Override
public String filterType() {
    return "pre";
}

@Override
public int filterOrder() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object run() {

    RequestContext ctx = getCurrentContext();

    String newBody = "{\"key\":\"value\"}";
    byte[] bytes = newBody.getBytes();

    ctx.setRequest(new HttpServletRequestWrapper(getCurrentContext().getRequest()) {
        @Override
        public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ServletInputStreamWrapper(bytes);
        }

        @Override
        public int getContentLength() {
            return bytes.length;
        }

        @Override
        public long getContentLengthLong() {
            return bytes.length;
        }
    });

    return null;
}
```

}